# Persisting data in Firebase Auth Emulator using Docker container in a specific directory

Tags: firebase, docker

I am trying to run Firebase Auth Emulator in a Docker container and persist the data in a volume.
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache openjdk17-jre-headless && \
npm install -g firebase-tools && mkdir data
COPY firebase.json ./
ENTRYPOINT ["firebase", "--project", "docker-emulator", "emulators:start", "--import=data", "--export-on-exit=data"]
```

Then, this is the command I use to run the container:

```
docker run --name auth_test -p 4000:4000 -p 9099:9099 -d -v auth_vol:/data authserver
```

When I run `docker stop auth_test` then I expect my data to be exported to the /data folder, but instead data are exported to a folder with a random name like firebase-export and so on.

What am I missing? Does this have something to do with Docker's signal handling?

Answer (score 0):

When using the Firebase emulator for exporting, specifying a directory that already exists will cause a failure. If the export fails, it will default to exporting to the current directory with a randomly generated name. To resolve this, specify a non-existent directory name within a docker volume, one level down

```
firebase emulators:start --project demo-project --import /data/firebase --export-on-exit
```